# Output-Table w. custom properties displays wrong count?

Tags: powershell

I have an XML-File as seen in the code below and I want to output a summary-table in PowerShell.
The table should contain the `SequenceName` and the **count** of child-notes named `Package`.

- If the package-count is **greater than 1**, then everything is fine.
- If the package-count is **ONE**, than I get no result.

I did strap down my whole code to get a clean and reproducible example.
Just copy and paste the following code for easy reproduction:

```
[xml]$Xml = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Sequences>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Seq1</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package1</PackageFolder>
      </Package>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package2</PackageFolder>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
  <Sequence>
    <SequenceName>Seq2</SequenceName>
    <SequencePackages>
      <Package>
        <PackageFolder>Package3</PackageFolder>
      </Package>
    </SequencePackages>
  </Sequence>
</Sequences>
"@

Clear-Host

$SummaryProperties = @(
    @{ Name = "SequenceName"; Expression = { $_.SequenceName } };
    @{ Name = "PackageCount"; Expression = { $_.SequencePackages.Package.Where( { $_.PackageActive -ne "False" } ).Count } };
)

$Xml.Sequences.Sequence | Select-Object -Property $SummaryProperties | Format-Table
```

The result looks like this:

```
SequenceName PackageCount
------------ ------------
Seq1                    2
Seq2
```

As you see, the column "PackageCount" of "Seq2" is empty, but it should be "1".

The expected result would look like this:

```
SequenceName PackageCount
------------ ------------
Seq1                    2
Seq2                    1
```

How to correct this easily?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues going on here. The `where()` method typically returns a collection with the `count` property available regardless of the number of objects in the collection. However in your single object query, you are retrieving a type `System.Xml.XmlElement`. That object type does not support the `.where()` method due to a bug as noted in [mklement0’s post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58686842/11025476). Because of bug, the `count` property you are attempting to access is not available  but ***should be***<sup>[1]</sup>. To consistently get the `count` property, you may use something like `Measure-Object` and access its `Count` property.

```
$SummaryProperties = @(
    @{ Name = "SequenceName"; Expression = { $_.SequenceName } };
    @{ Name = "PackageCount"; Expression = {
        ($_.SequencePackages.Package | Where-Object {
            $_.PackageActive -ne "False" } | Measure-Object).Count
        }
    };
)

$Xml.Sequences.Sequence | Select-Object -Property $SummaryProperties | Format-Table

# Output

SequenceName PackageCount
------------ ------------
Seq1                    2
Seq2                    1
```

---

<sup>[1]: Piping a single `XmlElement` object into `where-object` also exhibits the same bugged behavior.</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much!!! - I can't remember, why I did use the `.where()` method here. With your code and `Where-Object` it is also better readable for me.

Comment: I appreciate the update, @AdminOfThings. As a potential point of interest: That `($_.SequencePackages.Package | Where-Object { $_.PackageActive -ne "False" }).Count` doesn't work - i.e., that an `XmlElement` instance doesn't have the PS-provided `.Count` property that contains `1` for scalars is another manifestation of presumably the same bug.

Comment: @mklement0 I added another update for that bug behavior

Comment: Thanks, @AdminOfThings, but the use of `Where-Object` is actually incidental to the problem, which can be reproduced directly with `([xml] '<foo/>').DocumentElement.Count`, which _should_ return `1` (and does in PowerShell _Core_), but returns `$null` in Windows PowerShell (because the property isn't present).

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:**

- What you're seeing is a ***bug* in Windows PowerShell** that has since been corrected in PowerShell *Core* - your code works as-is in PowerShell Core.
- The **workaround** is to use `@($_.SequencePackages.Package)` instead of `$_.SequencePackages.Package`, to ensure that the `.Where()` array method works as intended.

```
$SummaryProperties = 
  @{ Name = "SequenceName"; Expression = { $_.SequenceName } },
  @{ Name = "PackageCount"; Expression = {
    # Note the @(...)
    @($_.SequencePackages.Package).Where( { $_.PackageActive -ne "False" } ).Count } 
  }
```

<sup>Also note the simplified array-construction syntax: `,`-separated elements, no need for (outer) `@(...)`</sup>

---

The PSv4+ [`.Where()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays#where) is meant to be available on *any* object, even on *scalars* (single objects), although the typical use case is to filter *collections*, similar to what the `Where-Object` cmdlet does in pipelines.

The `.Where()` method always returns a collection of type `[System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[psobject]]`, whose `.Count` property reflects the number of objects returned (the count of objects for which the script-block argument (`{ ... }`) evaluated to `$true`).

The aforementioned bug is that in Windows PowerShell the `.Where()` method is unexpectedly not  available on certain *scalars*, such as instances of type `[System.Xml.XmlElement]` - which is what `$_.SequencePackages.Package` returns for the 2nd `$Xml.Sequences.Sequence` element sent to `Select-Object`, because it happens to have just *one* child element.

For instance, the following, which *should* work (and does in PowerShell *Core*) fails with `Method invocation failed because [System.Xml.XmlElement] unexpectedly does not contain a method named 'Where'` in Windows PowerShell:

```
# OK in PowerShell Core, fails in Windows PowerShell
([xml] '<foo/>').DocumentElement.Where({ $true }).OuterXml
```

While trying to call a non-existent method normally results in a statement-terminating error, as in the above command, such an error is quietly ignored if it occurs in the `Expression` script-block value of a calculated property, and the script block then effectively returns "nothing" (the `[System.Management.Automation.Internal.AutomationNull]::Value` singleton, which is treated like `$null` in expressions), which explains your output.

However, *arrays* in Windows PowerShell always have the `.Where()` method, so wrapping an expression in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--) ensures that the result is an array and that `.Where()` can therefore be called.